# hard time relating models in rails, am I missing something?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im reaching out to see maybe someone can figure this out and what I'm missing. It's not the first time I've related a model to a user model to grab and associate the user_id with, however this time the wording itself I think might be the problem. Anyways take a look and let me know if I've missed anything;

so I've got my user.rb model;

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :user_id

   has_many :newfbtimelinestories
end
```

then I've got my new_fbtimeline_story.rb model;

```
class NewFbtimelineStory < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
end
```

`Story` and `Stories` ... everything I've done so far with all other relations was `group` -> `groups` ... in this case there is a story or stories. I've also tried the following;

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :user_id

   has_many :new_fbtimeline_stories
end
```

or

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :user_id

   has_many :new_fbtimeline_story
end
```

or

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :user_id

   has_many :NewFbtimelineStories
end
```

It's been a while since I did a relation. :)

Comment: ok so I've tried doing `user_id: User.current[:id]` in model on NewFbtimelineStory.create like so `NewFbtimelineStory.create({user_id: User.current[:id]})` but before in another model all I had to do was `SomeModel.create({user_id: User.current})... little confused. sorry.

Comment: Second one is the one you want, what error are you getting?

Comment: I believe you have to put `attr_accessible :user_id` in `NewFbtimelineStory`, not in `User`. Is that the problem?

Comment: @japed you mean `SomeModel.create({user_id: User.current})` is the one i should use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
| User |         | NewFbtimelineStory |
|------|         |--------------------|
|      |         | id                 |
| id   |1-------*| user_id            |
|______|         |____________________|

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :new_fbtimeline_stories
end

class NewFbtimelineStory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  attr_accessible :user_id
end
```

Comment: Thanks! I was relating to my user the wrong way from within the NewFbtimelimeStory model... :) Figured out I would just use User.current.new_fbtimeline_stories.create({})...